# why one table is updating and the other not in laravel?

Tags: laravel

When I click the edit button, I am trying to bring data from two tables and them update them together. One is user table and other on is user detail table.
when I update the information, user table is getting updated but user_detail table is not getting updated rather creating a new row. how to solve that?

The same code is working for one table while it is not working for the other.

This is my update function.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
       {
         // $this->validate($request,[
         //     'title'=>'required',
        //     'body'=>'required',
        // ]);
     //$user=new User;
     $user = User::find($id);
     $user->student_no=$request->input('student_no');
     $user->email=$request->input('email');
     $user->save();

     $user_detail=new Profile;
     $user_detail = Profile::find($id);
     $user_detail->student_no=$request->input('student_no');
     $user_detail->profile_pic=$request->input('CID');
      $user_detail->CID=$request->input('CID');
      $user_detail->DOB=$request->input('DOB');
      $user_detail->mobile_no=$request->input('mobile_no');
      $user_detail->joining_year=$request->input('joining_year');
      $user_detail->graduation_year=$request->input('graduation_year');
      $user_detail->program_id=$request->input('programe_id');
      $user_detail->work_experience=$request->input('work_experience');
      $user_detail->save();

     return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success','Post Updated');
```

The user table is getting updated but user_detail is not.

Comment: What value does the call on "save" return for the Profile? It may be failing without erroring out.

Comment: dd ($user_detail) after this line $user_detail = Profile::find($id);

Answer (score 1):

remove line,

```
$user_detail=new Profile;
```

and in line,

```
$user_detail = Profile::find($id);
```

here you can't do like this. You have to do something like this

```
$user_detail = Profile::where('user_id','=',$id)->first();
```

then your code should look like this,

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
       {
         // $this->validate($request,[
         //     'title'=>'required',
        //     'body'=>'required',
        // ]);
     //$user=new User;
     $user = User::find($id);
     $user->student_no=$request->input('student_no');
     $user->email=$request->input('email');
     $user->save();

    $user_detail = Profile::where('user_id','=',$id)->first();
     $user_detail->student_no=$request->input('student_no');
     $user_detail->profile_pic=$request->input('CID');
      $user_detail->CID=$request->input('CID');
      $user_detail->DOB=$request->input('DOB');
      $user_detail->mobile_no=$request->input('mobile_no');
      $user_detail->joining_year=$request->input('joining_year');
      $user_detail->graduation_year=$request->input('graduation_year');
      $user_detail->program_id=$request->input('programe_id');
      $user_detail->work_experience=$request->input('work_experience');
      $user_detail->save();

     return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success','Post Updated');
```

Comment: @dilusha_dasanyaka Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. i was having another doubt.if you could help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete `$user_detail=new Profile;`
2. Use relations for update user details.
3. Read about `$request->all()` and `Mass Assignment` in Laravel.
4. Make form validation in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

$user_detail = Profile::find($id);
in this line you are checking the profile data with the primary key of the profile table which might does not exist

You can try with

```
$user_detail = Profile::where('user_id',$id)->first();

user_id is the fk on profiles table from user id.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove line `$user_detail=new Profile;`
and update line `$user_detail = Profile::find($id);` as following

```
$user_detail = Profile::where('user_id',$id)->first()
```

Answer (score 0):

there two three things with your query.

```
$user_detail=new Profile;
$user_detail = Profile::find($id);
```

first of all no need for ***new profile***  line . It just made new object but you don't need that sine your going to update someone profile,
Now print your second line response weather your getting any response from it and also is it correct one because your finding id not user_id .
otherwise there is no problem with that. 
hope you will find solution in this.